# ¿Como hacer un campo en un formulario para ingresar una firma manuscrita y que se guarde como un documento?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Actualmente me encuentro haciendo un proyecto con html, php, javascript, donde se basa en generar reportes y visitas técnicas, en un formulario de visita técnica se debe exigir la firma del cliente, pero se quiere que el usuario pueda hacer su firma directamente desde el celular o Tablet donde se está llenando el formulario y luego este formulario se guarde tanto en la base como también documento pdf.

Comment: Te recomiendo que modifiques la pregunta, añade algo de tu código para dar contexto. Si no tu pregunta podría ser eliminada.

Comment: Tu pregunta se compone de 1) crear firma, 2) Guardar el formulario  en base de datos y 3) Guardar el formulario en PDF. Debes hacer una sola pregunta por publicación y tal como te lo señaló @AarónRojas debes colocar el código de lo que llevas realizado

Answer (score 0):

Hola podes usar una libreria que te facilite el trabajo. Te paso un ejemplo de una pero hay muchas

https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

// Returns signature image as data URL (see https://mdn.io/todataurl for the list of possible parameters)
signaturePad.toDataURL(); // save image as PNG
signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); // save image as JPEG
signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5); // save image as JPEG with 0.5 image quality
signaturePad.toDataURL("image/svg+xml"); // save image as SVG

// Draws signature image from data URL (mostly uses https://mdn.io/drawImage under-the-hood)
// NOTE: This method does not populate internal data structure that represents drawn signature. Thus, after using #fromDataURL, #toData won't work properly.
signaturePad.fromDataURL("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...");

// Draws signature image from data URL and alters it with the given options
signaturePad.fromDataURL("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...", { ratio: 1, width: 400, height: 200, xOffset: 100, yOffset: 50 });

// Returns signature image as an array of point groups
const data = signaturePad.toData();

// Draws signature image from an array of point groups
signaturePad.fromData(data);

// Draws signature image from an array of point groups, without clearing your existing image (clear defaults to true if not provided)
signaturePad.fromData(data, { clear: false });

// Clears the canvas
signaturePad.clear();

// Returns true if canvas is empty, otherwise returns false
signaturePad.isEmpty();

// Unbinds all event handlers
signaturePad.off();

// Rebinds all event handlers
signaturePad.on();
```